# How to cast time in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get a TimeString from 08:00:00 to 08:00.

I would like to cast time like this:

```
protected $casts = [
    'opens' => 'time:H:i',
    'closes' => 'time:H:i',
];
```

without using mutators like getOpensAttribute().

In my migration I'm using:

```
$table->time('opens')->nullable();
$table->time('closes')->nullable();
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

i think you can create a custom cast
for example:

Generate a custom cast with:

```
php artisan make:cast TimeCast
```

TimeCast

```
public function get($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
{
    return  Carbon::parse($value)->format('H:i');
}
```

finally you can use it as

```
protected $casts = [
    'your_time_to_cast' => TimeCast::class
];
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting), the only supported cast types are:

> integer, real, float, double, string, boolean, object,  array,
> collection, date, datetime, and timestamp.

Therefore you have to convert your time to string either before you store it or after you retrieve it from the database.

Comment: Altho correct there is no type cast available for this, one can still define an accessor that will transform the eloquent attribute value when it is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is overriding toArray() method on the model
here's an example from my code from inside the model file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model
{
 use HasFactory;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
];

/* this is the related part */
public function toArray()
{
    $array = parent::toArray();
    $array['starts_at'] = $array['starts_at']->format('H:i:s');
    $array['ends_at'] = $array['ends_at']->format('H:i:s');
    return $array;
}

}
```

Comment: can you provide the full example in your answer? like where to replace this snippet ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by [defining an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on your model like so:

```
protected function opens(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn($value) => Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $value)->format('H:i'),
    );
}

protected function closes(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn($value) => Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $value)->format('H:i'),
    );
}
```

Depending on your needs you might want to also [add the name of this attribute to the `$appends` property](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) to make it visible when serializing your model:

```
protected $appends = ['opens', 'closes'];
```

Please note that my syntax is valid for Laravel version 9+. For older versions, use the below syntax instead:

```
public function getOpensAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $value)->format('H:i');
}
public function getClosesAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $value)->format('H:i');
}
```